# Python, Run shell scripts in parllel

Tags: python

I've list of scripts

```
['abc/start.sh', 'xyz/start.sh','dbc/start.sh', 'acb/start.sh']
```

I need to run all these scripts parallel. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at `subprocess` module. This module is a replacement for the old `os.spawn` and `os.popen` etc. functions

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html